# Cannot delete a column from MS Excel using officegen

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, ms-office, office-js

I am generating charts as PPT using officegen. Everything is working fine except that when i edit chart values by right click and choosing Edit data> Edit data in excel, and delete(by right clicking) an entire column from excel, it shows an error as *Excel found a problem with one or more formula references in this work sheet*. Can anybody help me to fix this issue.? Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Popup]

Comment: u r using officegen or any other method

Comment: i think it's a  officegen issue

Comment: i just confused this issue where happening on backend  ppt creation or ms offiice issue